Running Curl 10.0.1.1 on xterm terminal (h3,h4) returns "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.1.1 port 80 after x ms: No route to host" error
I am trying to emulate server requests using curl command from client nodes (in this case, h3, h4) in mininet. To run the requests, I first started xterm terminals in mininet CLI to create nodes (h1, h2) as servers and (h3,h4) as hosts. I started python3 -m htt.server 80 in both h1 and h2 and tried to curl each of them using the command curl 10.0.1.1 from both h3 and h4 nodes. The 10.0.1.1 is the ip address of the pox loadbalancer controller and the servers 1 and 2 each have 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, respectively.
I tried sending the curl commands from each of the above hosts in different sessions and each time it would result in either no route to host or connection refused or connection timed out. For this particular session, the error I'm consistently getting is no route to host with x amount of ms.
All the nodes (servers and hosts ) above are virtual nodes created in mininet xterm terminals. Any idea how to successfully curl the servers from each of the hosts above?
